# Rundeck job API: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common

Tags: ssl, jetty, sslhandshakeexception, rundeck

Upgraded from Rundeck **3.0.2 (API v30)** to **3.2.1 (API v34)**. Yum/RPM install, RHEL 7.

I configured SSL following Rundeck documentation and modeling after my existing working installation. SSL works fine via the web, and works fine when I hit the job REST API using curl, however when our MuleSoft application hits the REST API, it's failing with a handshake_failure:

```
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
qtp1539575645-26, fatal error: 40: no cipher suites in common
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
qtp1539575645-26, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
qtp1539575645-26, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
qtp1539575645-26, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
```

I confirmed that MuleSoft trusts the Rundeck server's cert. Previously I wasn't explicitly including/excluding any ciphersuites in my Rundeck ssl config, but I forced MuleSoft to use a particular suite, and then added that suite to /etc/sysconfig/rundeckd using the `-Drundeck.jetty.connector.ssl.includedCipherSuites=(insert suite here)` parameter, however we still receive the "no cipher suites in common" error.

Adding the `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` parm to `/etc/sysconfig/rundeckd` adds the handshake details to `service.log`. I can see the list of *excluded* ciphersuites, but I don't see confirmation that it's including the one(s) I added. I do see the parm in the process details of the running JVM.

This feels like a client issue on MuleSoft's side, and we're reaching out to the vendor however I find it odd that when I explicitly include the cipher suite that the client is sending it still doesn't see one in common. Perhaps I'm using the `-Drundeck.jetty.connector.ssl.includedCipherSuites` incorrectly?

My `/etc/sysconfig/rundeckd` file that I'm testing with currently looks like this:

```
export RUNDECK_WITH_SSL=true
export RDECK_HTTPS_PORT=4443
RDECK_JVM_OPTS="-Drundeck.jaaslogin=true \
       -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/rundeck/jaas-multiauth.conf \
       -Dloginmodule.name=multiauth \
       -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/rundeck/ssl/truststore \
       -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks \
       -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol \
       -Drundeck.jetty.connector.ssl.includedCipherSuites=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 \
       -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.LEVEL=DEBUG \
       -Djavax.net.debug=ssl"
```

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: Why do you try to restrict yourself to a single cipher (which might not be supported by either your client or the server) instead of letting the client use the default cipher set in the hope that the server will pick a supported one? And note that "no shared cipher" is completely unrelated to trusting the certificate or not.

Comment: Hi Steffen, thanks for response. Ultimately we'll be using the default ciphers and not explicitly including/excluding any, but in this case we're only picking one for troubleshooting - making sure the client and server are explicitly specifying the same one just to force them to use/agree on that one as a troubleshooting step. We definitely won't run that way in Production. As for the cert being trusted, yes it's unrelated but I'm just showing that I'm covering my bases and proving out that I have SSL configured correctly to begin with.

Comment: If you pick a single one then you need to be sure that it is implemented by both client and server, which does not seem to be the case here. Just specifying it will not help if it is not actually supported by the TLS stacks.

Comment: My SSL log tells me that the client is sending the one cipher suite that my Rundeck instance is currently configured to accept (as a troubleshooting measure). How can I confirm that this particular cipher suite is supported by Rundeck? I tried adding the `-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.LEVEL=DEBUG` parm to the JVM which I thought would show all supported suites, but I'm not seeing it. It only tells me all of the UNsupported suites. Even before explicitly telling Rundeck to accept one specific suite, I can't believe that NONE of the ciphersuites that my client uses are supported.

Comment: If you say that it works with curl I would recommend to check which cipher was used in this case (`curl -v ...`)

Comment: I'll confirm that, thanks. Looking at my `/etc/sysconfig/rundeckd` sample above, am I mis-using `-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.LEVEL=DEBUG`? Having added that to my file and bouncing Rundeck, I'm expecting to see in my `service.log` a list of supported ciphersuites... but not seeing it.

Comment: The option you use is the one officially documented so I guess it the the correct one. I have no idea what you see though as debug output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the client, MuleSoft, required that the Rundeck server's SSL certificate had the 'KeyUsage=digitalSignature' extension. Adding this extension resolved the problem.